# Coulomb’s Law Explained by Electric Fields

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

Could someone help me understand this analogy from this MIT Lecture? How do electric field lines apply “lateral pressure”. Are the field lines trying to “bend back” to equilibrium due to the lines being “in tension” and thats the “pressure”?I understand this is probably whats not actually happening but I would like to understand the analogy better.
[Here](https://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/802TEAL3D/visualizations/guidedtour/Tour.htm#_Toc27302322) is a link to the full lecture/notes. Theres also some neat animations that they have generated.

[image]

Comment: It is a quite good explanation by MIT

Comment: @DebanjanBiswas I agree its good i feel like im just missing something, where is the pressure coming from? How do the lines cause it?

Comment: These field lines can be compared with springs. When there are two springs in front of each other and you push both towards each other, there is a pressure. And when you release them, the springs will return to their previous state.

Comment: @DebanjanBiswas do to the internal tensions in the sping? Like how it states field lines are “in tension”?

Comment: Yes! These field lines act completely as springs